# Dreaded "could not find a base address that matches scheme http" how to make it work with SSL?

Tags: wcf, ssl

This questions has been asked a lot but every answer I find is related to something I've already applied. Give the below info, how do I get my service working with SSL?

I'm trying to get a JSONP response using ajax from a WCF service that in exchange is connected to a middleware service. My request consists of two string.

I have the following xml inside my web.config under an **application BLL** which in turn is located under **a site X**:

```
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"
                 name="LocationService">
            <endpoint
                address=""
                      contract="ILocationService"
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
                      behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>         
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
```

A bit further in the config:

```
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" >
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
```

The service behaviour:

```
<behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
</behavior>
```

The IIS settings of this application:

- Require SSL is checked
- Client certificates: Require

The bindings of the site where the BLL app is located, are as follows:

- type: http; port: 80; IP Address: 10.xx.xxx.xxx
- type: https; port: 443; IP Address: 10.xx.xxx.xxx

This should work, shouldn't it? I presume the endpoint and binding info of this endpoint is not needed? Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: How are you testing your service? What is being used to host the for this test?

Comment: I'm trying to contact the service through an ajax call

Comment: That doesn't really me enough: what are you requesting? I assume you're using JavaScript running web browser rather than a WCF-based client, so are you sure you're requesting the right endpoint? And what are you hosting the service in? Can you run your test scenario successfully from IIS Express?

Comment: See my answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue.

The servicebehaviour didn't have httpsGetEnabled set to true. 
So it had to be this:

```
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
```

After this was added however, another issue came up.

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].
```

By changing the mex endpoint to allow secure metadata to be passed with the same binding info as my service (more info: [Microsoft MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395212.aspx)), the error dissapeared:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="webHttpBinding" name="MetadataBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"/>
```

The final issue I got, was that I hadn't set the security properly. Instead of what I've written in my question, it should be:

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="false">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Adjusting all that provided me with the jsonp result I needed.

I found an article that explains the configuration process thoroughly: [Microsoft MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/imayak/archive/2008/09/12/wcf-2-way-ssl-security-using-certificates.aspx)